# How to iterate over kinetic groups

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Is it possible to iterate over kinetic groups?
Here is what I have:

```
Layer
  -ParentGroup
     -kinetic image
     - childGroup
         - kinetic rectangle
         -kinetic text
```

I have only one kinetic image, but multiple childGroups. Each childGroup has a label which is unique (2 chilGroups can't have the same label). Let's say that now I would like to delete childGroup which label is =1.
I need to select the right childGroup , then `childGroup.hide()`

Is there a way to iterate over all the kinetic groups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ani is right in using the `get()` function.

To answer your question specifically, you can **iterate over all Kinetic.Groups** by using the `get()` function like this:

```
var groups = layer.get('Group')
```

Which returns an array of all the Kinetic Group objects inside the specified container (in this case, `layer`)

By the way if you wan't to delete a Kinetic Node you should either use [destroy](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Node.html#destroy) or [remove](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Node.html#remove)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get()` function described here:
http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#get

Like this:

```
var childGroup = ParentGroup.get('.child1')[0];
childGroup.hide(); // to hide OR 
childGroup.remove(); // to remove but preserve data that can still be referenced
childGroup.destroy(); // to completely delete it
```

OR using labels like this (as @projeqht suggested in comments)

```
var childGroup = ParentGroup.get('#child1')[0];
childGroup.hide(); // childGroup.remove();
```

Comment: I would reserve using **.names** for grouping and selecting multiple objects together like a class, and rather use an **#id** to select **one** specific group in the way that you suggested. Like this: container.get('#child1')[0]; As @user1499220 stated, each group has a **unique** label, so each group should also be **unique**.

Comment: @Ani  , thank you guys for your answers. I have one more question, is it possible in kineticJS and javascript to determine on which group id, a click event is happening? Basically, I have many shapes on the layer, and when I click on one of them, I would like to know which id shape I'm clicking on. Thank you in advance

Comment: @user1499220 you can bind event handlers to all the objects you require to handle click events and use keyword `this` to access the id inside the handler, is that what you require?

Comment: @user1499220 This is what you are looking for: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-get-event-shape-with-kineticjs/ The example selects the **name**, but you can easily set an id and use the **getId()** method instead.